# Run node cron every O'clock hour

Tags: node.js, cron, node-cron

I have below node cron setup that runs every hour.

```
const { CronJob } = require('cron');

const Job1 = new CronJob('0 0 */1 * * *', (async () => {
  let response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/todo`);
  response = await response.json();
  infoLogger.log({
    date: new Date().toISOString(),
    level: 'info',
    env: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    client: CLIENT_URL,
    method: 'GET',
    api: '/todo',
    response,
  });
}));
```

But the problem is it runs every hour the moment app starts. If it was started at 6:15, It will run again at 7:15.

I want it to be run eaxctly at O'clock i.e at 5:00, 6:00 ... 12:00, 13:00 and so on.

So, If app was started at 6:15, It should run again 7:00 and then 8:00 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Cron value to ('0 0 0-23 * * *').

It will work.